# Using getter and setter on an object property that has his own properties

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I'm fairly new to getters and setters and am looking for a way to listen for changes in an object to store the data immediately, without calling a `Save()` function everytime a value gets changed. This is how I do it right now:

```
var myObject = {
    Data: {
        enabled: true,
        show: false
    },
    Save: function () {
        //store myObject.Data to local storage
    },
    Load: function () {
        //load data from local storage and assign it to myObject.Data
    },
    doSomething: function () {
        myObject.Load();
        if (myObject.Data.enabled) {
            myObject.Data.show = true;
            myObject.Save();
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to optimize this code so everytime a property in `myObject.Data` is changed, `myObject.Save()` is executed. The problem I'm experiencing is that it seems only possible to define a getter for a property that has just one value, but not for a property that is an object itself.

```
var myObj = {
    _Data: {
        a: 0,
        b: 1,
        c: 3
    },
    set Data (a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
};

myObj.Data.a = 2;
```

This obviously doesn't work since `myObj.Data` is not an object and doesn't have the same properties as `myObj._Data`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely interested in the [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object.

I used a very simple debounce function `callHandler` in order to avoid calling the `onSet` method dozens of times during array modifications. Otherwise, `[1, 2, 3].splice(0, 1)` would call the set handler once per item in the original array.

```js
'use strict';
var myObject = {
    Data: {
        a: [1, 2, 3],
        b: {c: ['test']}
    },
    Save: function() {
        console.log('Save called');
    },
}

function recursiveProxy(target, onSet) {
    // For performance reasons, onSet will only be called one millesecond
    // after the set handler has last been called.
    var timeout;
    function callHandler() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(onSet, 1);
    }

    var recursiveHandler = {
        get: function(target, property) {
            // If the property is something that could contain another object,
            // we want to proxy it's properties as well.
            if (typeof target[property] == 'object' && target[property] != null) {
                return new Proxy(target[property], recursiveHandler);
            }

            return target[property];
        },
        set: function(target, property, value) {
            console.log('Set called - queueing onSet');
            callHandler();
            target[property] = value;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return new Proxy(target, recursiveHandler);
}

myObject.Data = recursiveProxy(myObject.Data, myObject.Save);

myObject.Data.a.splice(0, 1);
myObject.Data.b.c[0] = 'test 2';
```

Comment: Nice solution! I don't think the return value is needed though.

Comment: Keep in mind that Proxy is ES6+ and will only work in new browser and NodeJS v6+

Comment: @trincot, assuming strict mode, it is important. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set#Return_value

Comment: You're right, strict mode makes the difference. I wonder why they made that difference, when strict mode existed before proxies.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me a lot.  But one question: It doesn't seem to work if a property of `Data` is an Array or an Object, e.g. with `b: [0,1,2,3]`, using `splice()` on this property won't trigger the Proxy. Any advice?

Comment: @RiV, that's a bit more complicated... looking into it.

Comment: @RiV- just edited, this makes browsing the object in the developer's console a bit tedious, but it appears to do what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [Defining a getter on existing objects using defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

> To append a getter to an existing object later at any time, use
>   [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).
>
> ```
> var o = { a:0 }
>
> Object.defineProperty(o, "b", { get: function () { return this.a + 1; } });
>
> console.log(o.b) // Runs the getter, which yields a + 1 (which is 1)
> ```

For e.g:

```
var Data = {
    enable: true,
    show: false
};

Object.defineProperty(Data, 'doSomething', {
    get: function() {
        // get something;
    },
    set: function(something) {
        // set something
    }
});
```